# different padding for different pages with twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, padding

I'm starting a new rails project and added twitter bootstrap (since i've heard good things about it). This is a beginner question but, how do I add background images that span the entire hight/width of a page without letting twitter-bootstrap's default top and left padding get in the way? Is there a basic setup I haven't come across yet? How do I remove that padding for a specific page and yet still let the padding remain in the rest of the app? Is this padding beneficial?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the padding defined? You could just add a new class to that element, and chain them, giving that a higher priority. If bootstrap defines `body { padding: 20px; }`, just give your body a class like `<body class="custom">` and define it with `body.custom { padding: 0; }`

Comment: not sure why this isn't working: `body.coming-soon-page
{
  padding-top: -60px;
  padding-left:-20px;
}`

Comment: not yet. default body padding for twitter bootstrap is `body {
padding-top: 60px;
padding-left: 20px;
}`

Comment: @NewB - Adjusting the padding in the way you've written above is not the way to reset their current padding. Just set them to "0".

Comment: @BillyMoat, yeah, i've tried `0px` as well. so far it hasn't moved.

Comment: if it helps troubleshoot. when i set the `background-color: #000000;` the background color doesn't change either. so i think it's a selector issue. is there a way to give precedence in css? `body.coming-soon-page { css stuff }` isn't working

Comment: i added twitter bootstrap to my rails app using the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem. the css.scss i added manually. i don't think the stylesheet is being loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the background image to the body, as it would not be affected by the padding

```
body.my-page{
  background-image: url('my-image');
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

or add a `absolute`/ 'fixed` positioned container w/ the full width & height and apply the background image to that container.

```
<div class="bg"></div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.my-page .bg{
  background-image: url('my-image');
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
} 

.my-page .container{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: i'm trying to put a special background on my `coming-soon` page and don't want it to infringe on the styles/elements in the rest of my app. separating styles by page (or at least for the single static coming soon page is the objective).

Comment: you could apply a custom class per page the `body` as already suggested in the comments. Both of the methods i described would work with a custom class prefix (will update the answer)

Comment: as you already might have jQuery in your setup, you could also take a look at http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/ for fullscreen background images.